# Front-end edition K2 with joomla2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, frontend

I've followed first the basic advice given here (http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-how-to-enable-frontend-editing-in-k2-component.html). I believe without doing anything wrong.

My problem is that even logged in as an admin on the frontend I cannot edit K2 articles. Because the Edit button does not appear a the top of my article. It works for Joomla article though just K2's seems to be a problem.

Anyone knows where I should look into ? I'm not familiar with Joomla btw.

Thanks a lot, cheers,

NM

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't edit K2 items in the front end as you can do with Joomla articles.
In K2 you need to create a user group with front-end editing privilege.
**Joomla administration-> menu K2 -> User Groups**

Create a group with all privileges and no filter for the K2 categories at the bottom. Next you need to assign users who will have editing privileges to this group. Still in the K2 administration panel, click **Users** on the left menu. From the list of users displayed, Edit the ones that should be assigned to the group previously created.

You can now login in the front-end of the site and you should be able to edit the K2 items.

[image]